# Chamar função sem precisar instanciar novamente o plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Estou fazendo um plugin de drag and drop junto de um colega, porém estamos tendo um problema. Quando instanciamos o plugin ele roda normalmente, porém se quisermos chamar alguma função desse plugin na variavel em que ele foi instanciado sempre precisamos instanciar ele novamente, o que tem gerado bugs.

Eu instancio o plugin:

```
var dad = $('.dad').dad();
```

E depois quero chamar a função para `getPosition` para saber a ordem final dos itens.

```
var ordem = dad.getPosition();
```

Porém diz que a getPosition não é uma função no console. A única forma de fazer funcionar é instanciando o plugin novamente.

```
var ordem = dad.dad().getPosition();
```

O código do plugin segue a baixo.

```
$(function(){
    function O_dad(){
        var self=this;
        this.x=0;
        this.y=0;
        this.target=false;
        this.clone=false;
        this.placeholder=false;
        this.cloneoffset={x:0,y:0};
        this.move=function(e){
            self.x=e.pageX;
            self.y=e.pageY;
            if (self.clone!=false && self.target!=false){
                self.clone.css({top:self.y-self.cloneoffset.y,left:self.x-self.cloneoffset.x});
            }else{

            }
        };
        $(window).on('mousemove',function(e){
            self.move(e)
        });

    }
    $.prototype.dad=function(opts){
        var me=this;
        $(this).each(function(){
            var mouse;
            mouse=new O_dad();
            var target,active,callback,daddy,childrenClass,jQclass,cloneClass;
            childrenClass='dads-children';
            cloneClass='dads-children-clone';
            jQclass='.dads-children';
            daddy=$(this);
            daddy.addClass('dad-container');
            if ( typeof opts != "undefined" && typeof opts.target !== 'undefined'){
                target=daddy.find(opts.target);
            }else{
                target=daddy.children();
            }
            if ( typeof opts != "undefined" && typeof opts.callback !== 'undefined'){
                callback=opts.callback;
            }else{
                callback=false;
            }
            me.addDropzone=function(selector,func){
                $(selector).on('mouseenter',function(){
                    if (mouse.target!=false) {
                        mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'none'});
                        mouse.target.css({display: 'none'});

                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }
                }).on('mouseup',function(){
                    if (mouse.target!=false) {
                        mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'block'});
                        mouse.target.css({display: 'block'});
                        func(mouse.target);
                        children_replace();
                    }
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                }).on('mouseleave',function(){
                    if (mouse.target!=false){
                        mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'block'});
                        mouse.target.css({display: 'block'});
                    }
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                });
            };
            me.getPosition=function(){
                var positionArray = [];
                $(this).find(jQclass).each(function(){
                    positionArray[$(this).attr('data-dad-id')]=parseInt($(this).attr('data-dad-position'));
                });
                return positionArray;
            };
            $(document).on('mouseup',function(){
                children_replace();
            });
            function children_replace(){
                if (mouse.target!=false &&  mouse.clone!=false){
                    if (callback!=false){
                        callback(mouse.target);
                    }
                    var appear=mouse.target;
                    var desapear=mouse.clone;
                    var holder=mouse.placeholder;
                    var bLeft =0;Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-left-width')));
                    var bTop =0;Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-top-width')));
                    if ($.contains(daddy[0],mouse.target[0])){
                        mouse.clone.animate({top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top-bTop,left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left-bLeft},300,function(){
                            appear.css({visibility:'visible'}).removeClass('active');
                            desapear.remove();
                        });
                    }else{
                        mouse.clone.fadeOut(300,function(){
                            desapear.remove();
                        })
                    }
                    holder.remove();
                    mouse.clone=false;
                    mouse.placeholder=false;
                    mouse.target=false;
                    update_position(daddy);
                }
                $("html,body").removeClass('dad-noSelect');
            }
            function children_update(obj){
                if (mouse.target!=false && mouse.clone!=false) {
                    var newplace, origin;
                    origin = $('<span style="display:none"></span>');
                    newplace = $('<span style="display:none"></span>');
                    if (obj.prevAll().hasClass('active')){
                        obj.after(newplace);
                    }else{
                        obj.before(newplace);
                    }
                    mouse.target.before(origin);
                    newplace.before(mouse.target);
                    //update placeholder
                    mouse.placeholder.css({
                        top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top,
                        left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left,
                        width: mouse.target.outerWidth()-10,
                        height: mouse.target.outerHeight()-10
                    });
                    //origin.before(obj);
                    origin.remove();
                    newplace.remove();
                }
            }
            var order = 1;
            target.addClass(childrenClass).each(function(){
                if($(this).data('dad-id')==undefined){
                    $(this).attr('data-dad-id',order);
                }
                $(this).attr('data-dad-position',order);
                order++;
            });
            function update_position(e){
                var order = 1;
                e.find(jQclass).each(function(){
                    $(this).attr('data-dad-position',order);
                    order++;
                });
            }
            daddy.find(jQclass).on('mousedown touchstart',function(e){
                if (mouse.target==false && e.which==1 && active==true){
                    // GET TARGET
                    mouse.target=$(this);

                    // ADD CLONE
                    mouse.clone=mouse.target.clone();
                    mouse.target.css({visibility:'hidden'}).addClass('active');
                    mouse.clone.addClass(cloneClass);
                    daddy.append(mouse.clone);

                    // ADD PLACEHOLDER
                    mouse.placeholder=$('<div></div>');
                    mouse.placeholder.addClass('dads-children-placeholder');
                    mouse.placeholder.css({
                        top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top,
                        left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left,
                        width: mouse.target.outerWidth()-10,
                        height: mouse.target.outerHeight()-10,
                        lineHeight: mouse.target.height()-18+'px'
                    }).text('drop here');
                    daddy.append(mouse.placeholder);

                    // GET OFFSET FOR CLONE
                    var difx,dify;
                    var bLeft =Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-left-width')));
                    var bTop =Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-top-width')));
                    difx=mouse.x-mouse.target.offset().left+daddy.offset().left+bLeft;
                    dify=mouse.y-mouse.target.offset().top+daddy.offset().top+bTop;
                    mouse.cloneoffset.x=difx;
                    mouse.cloneoffset.y=dify;

                    // REMOVE THE CHILDREN DAD CLASS AND SET THE POSITION ON SCREEN
                    mouse.clone.removeClass(childrenClass).css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:mouse.y-mouse.cloneoffset.y,
                        left:mouse.x-mouse.cloneoffset.x
                    });
                    // UNABLE THE TEXT SELECTION AND SET THE GRAB CURSOR
                    $("html,body").addClass('dad-noSelect');
                }
            }).on('mouseenter',function(){
                children_update($(this));
            });

        });

        return this;
    };
});
```

Comment: Podes mudar este jsFiddle para reproduzir o problema? -> http://jsfiddle.net/q5wjcuxv/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## O problema

O problema ocorre porque você está tentando adicionar as novas funções aos objetos retornados pelo jQuery, que logo serão descartados.

É importante lembrar que plugins jQuery retornam objetos jQuery e não os objetos do DOM. Um novo seletor jQuery irá criar um novo objeto jQuery com os elementos selecionados.

## Uma solução intermediária

Para que `dad.getPosition()` funcione do jeito proposto, é preciso adicionar a função no próprio jQuery da mesma forma que `.dad()`.

Porém esta não é a forma recomendada!

## Solução recomendada

Conforme o [guia do jQuery para criação de plugins](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/), não é recomendável adicionar várias funções para um determinado plugin. Isso leva a mais riscos de conflito com outros plugins.

O recomendável é adicionar apenas um método e chamar métodos do plugin de forma indireto, a exemplo de quase todas as bibliotecas. Exemplo:

```
(function( $ ) {
    $.fn.popup = function( action ) {
        if ( action === "open") {
            // Open popup code.
        }
        if ( action === "close" ) {
            // Close popup code.
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Fiz uma pequena refatoração no plugin para funcionar dessa forma. Veja como ficou:

```
(function( $ ) {
    var jQclass='.dads-children';

    function O_dad(){
        var self=this;
        this.x=0;
        this.y=0;
        this.target=false;
        this.clone=false;
        this.placeholder=false;
        this.cloneoffset={x:0,y:0};
        this.move=function(e){
            self.x=e.pageX;
            self.y=e.pageY;
            if (self.clone!=false && self.target!=false){
                self.clone.css({top:self.y-self.cloneoffset.y,left:self.x-self.cloneoffset.x});
            }else{

            }
        };
        $(window).on('mousemove',function(e){
            self.move(e)
        });
    }

    function addDropzone(selector,func){
        $(selector).on('mouseenter',function(){
            if (mouse.target!=false) {
                mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'none'});
                mouse.target.css({display: 'none'});

                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        }).on('mouseup',function(){
            if (mouse.target!=false) {
                mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'block'});
                mouse.target.css({display: 'block'});
                func(mouse.target);
                children_replace();
            }
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        }).on('mouseleave',function(){
            if (mouse.target!=false){
                mouse.placeholder.css({display: 'block'});
                mouse.target.css({display: 'block'});
            }
            $(this).removeClass('active');
        });
    };
    function getPosition(){
        var positionArray = [];
        $(this).find(jQclass).each(function(){
            positionArray[$(this).attr('data-dad-id')]=parseInt($(this).attr('data-dad-position'));
        });
        return positionArray;
    };

    function children_replace(){
        if (mouse.target!=false &&  mouse.clone!=false){
            if (callback!=false){
                callback(mouse.target);
            }
            var appear=mouse.target;
            var desapear=mouse.clone;
            var holder=mouse.placeholder;
            var bLeft =0;Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-left-width')));
            var bTop =0;Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-top-width')));
            if ($.contains(daddy[0],mouse.target[0])){
                mouse.clone.animate({top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top-bTop,left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left-bLeft},300,function(){
                    appear.css({visibility:'visible'}).removeClass('active');
                    desapear.remove();
                });
            }else{
                mouse.clone.fadeOut(300,function(){
                    desapear.remove();
                })
            }
            holder.remove();
            mouse.clone=false;
            mouse.placeholder=false;
            mouse.target=false;
            update_position(daddy);
        }
        $("html,body").removeClass('dad-noSelect');
    }

    function children_update(obj){
        if (mouse.target!=false && mouse.clone!=false) {
            var newplace, origin;
            origin = $('<span style="display:none"></span>');
            newplace = $('<span style="display:none"></span>');
            if (obj.prevAll().hasClass('active')){
                obj.after(newplace);
            }else{
                obj.before(newplace);
            }
            mouse.target.before(origin);
            newplace.before(mouse.target);
            //update placeholder
            mouse.placeholder.css({
                top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top,
                left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left,
                width: mouse.target.outerWidth()-10,
                height: mouse.target.outerHeight()-10
            });
            //origin.before(obj);
            origin.remove();
            newplace.remove();
        }
    }

    function update_position(e){
        var order = 1;
        e.find(jQclass).each(function(){
            $(this).attr('data-dad-position',order);
            order++;
        });
    }


    $.fn.dad = function(method) {

        $(this).each(function(){

            if ($(this).data('dad-activated')) {
                return;
            } else {
                $(this).data('dad-activated', true);
            }

            var mouse;
            mouse=new O_dad();
            var target,active,callback,daddy,childrenClass,jQclass,cloneClass;
            childrenClass='dads-children';
            cloneClass='dads-children-clone';
            daddy=$(this);
            daddy.addClass('dad-container');
            if ( typeof opts != "undefined" && typeof opts.target !== 'undefined'){
                target=daddy.find(opts.target);
            }else{
                target=daddy.children();
            }
            if ( typeof opts != "undefined" && typeof opts.callback !== 'undefined'){
                callback=opts.callback;
            }else{
                callback=false;
            }

            $(document).on('mouseup',function(){
                children_replace();
            });

            var order = 1;
            target.addClass(childrenClass).each(function(){
                if($(this).data('dad-id')==undefined){
                    $(this).attr('data-dad-id',order);
                }
                $(this).attr('data-dad-position',order);
                order++;
            });

            daddy.find(jQclass).on('mousedown touchstart',function(e){
                if (mouse.target==false && e.which==1 && active==true){
                    // GET TARGET
                    mouse.target=$(this);

                    // ADD CLONE
                    mouse.clone=mouse.target.clone();
                    mouse.target.css({visibility:'hidden'}).addClass('active');
                    mouse.clone.addClass(cloneClass);
                    daddy.append(mouse.clone);

                    // ADD PLACEHOLDER
                    mouse.placeholder=$('<div></div>');
                    mouse.placeholder.addClass('dads-children-placeholder');
                    mouse.placeholder.css({
                        top:mouse.target.offset().top-daddy.offset().top,
                        left:mouse.target.offset().left-daddy.offset().left,
                        width: mouse.target.outerWidth()-10,
                        height: mouse.target.outerHeight()-10,
                        lineHeight: mouse.target.height()-18+'px'
                    }).text('drop here');
                    daddy.append(mouse.placeholder);

                    // GET OFFSET FOR CLONE
                    var difx,dify;
                    var bLeft =Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-left-width')));
                    var bTop =Math.floor(parseFloat(daddy.css('border-top-width')));
                    difx=mouse.x-mouse.target.offset().left+daddy.offset().left+bLeft;
                    dify=mouse.y-mouse.target.offset().top+daddy.offset().top+bTop;
                    mouse.cloneoffset.x=difx;
                    mouse.cloneoffset.y=dify;

                    // REMOVE THE CHILDREN DAD CLASS AND SET THE POSITION ON SCREEN
                    mouse.clone.removeClass(childrenClass).css({
                        position:'absolute',
                        top:mouse.y-mouse.cloneoffset.y,
                        left:mouse.x-mouse.cloneoffset.x
                    });
                    // UNABLE THE TEXT SELECTION AND SET THE GRAB CURSOR
                    $("html,body").addClass('dad-noSelect');
                }
            }).on('mouseenter',function(){
                children_update($(this));
            });

        });

        if (method == 'getPosition') {
            return getPosition.apply( this );
        } else if (method == 'addDropzone') {
            return addDropzone.apply( this, arguments );
        } 

        return this;

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

A chamada muda um pouco, como o exemplo abaixo:

```
var myDad = $('.dad').dad();
var ordem = myDad.dad('getPosition');
```

Deixei um [exemplo alterado no JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/n0fkkp0w/).

### Observações importantes

Note que para não inicializar o plugin várias vezes, adicionei um `if` ao início que coloca uma flag `dad-activated`.

Após a inicialização do plugin, adicionei o código que chama os métodos do plugin indiretamente:

```
if (method == 'getPosition') {
    return getPosition.apply( this );
} else if (method == 'addDropzone') {
    return addDropzone.apply( this, arguments );
}
```

Note que removi as várias funções internas que estavam dentro do bloco e as coloquei no escopo do plugin. Isso foi somente para deixar o código mais limpo. Porém, recomendo que trabalhe dessa forma e, se possível, evite uso de variáveis compartilhadas entre métodos, como a `daddy` como na função `children_replace`, a qual poderia receber o objeto como parâmetro.

Uma última observação: ao invés de acessar atributos do tipo `data-*` com `attr()`, você pode usar a função [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: eu uso o `attr()` pois os `data-*` são modificados no `DOM` e como a função `data()` pega o valor original, me obriga a usar a função `attr()`

Comment: Não consegui usar o plugin dessa forma, o console não mostra nenhum erro, mas ele não está funcionando

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Não está 100% funcional porque movi alguns métodos e não ajustei variáveis globais. Infelizmente não tenho tempo para fazer todos os ajustes necessários. A resposta foi apenas para dar o caminho da solução. :(

Comment: vamos tentar adequar o código, tinha esquecido das variáveis globais, mas respondeu algumas outras duvidas que tínhamos sobre como fazer o plugin do jeito certo também, valeu :D

Comment: @RodrigoBorth Ok, desculpe mesmo estar meio sem tempo. Se continuar tendo problemas me avise que outro dia vejo com mais calma. Mas de qualquer forma acho que vcs dão conta ;)

Comment: https://github.com/williammustaffa/jquery.dad.js caso interesse, esse é o link para o projeto